# A Question about Avid Sibelius 2021 and Kontakt (.nki) instruments

Tags: notation, instruments, software, samples, sound-design

Since Sibelius is just using a version of Kontakt in the background to play its own sounds, can I build Sibelius Soundsets that are based on nothing but the .nki files in my authorized Kontakt Libraries? For instance, could I create a "Piano and Orchestra" soundtrack that mapped my favorite individual .nki instruments to Sibelius Sounds, so that I could create parts (on the Template Page where you lay out your score by instrument), using these custom instruments, labeled things like "Orchestra 2.0 - Elves Marching"?